# Has a baserunner ever been hit by a batted ball?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

Sometimes, the ball flies pretty low to the ground, about 6 feet or lower. Seeing as offensive players waiting on a base will often run as soon as the ball is hit, the possibility of them being hit by a ball is present.

So, has a baserunner ever been hit by a batted ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has this ever occurred?

[Yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-e_F28LkXc).

Rule 5.09(b)(7) in the [2016 MLB Rule Book](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf) states what is ruled in such an occurence:

> Any runner is out when:
>
> - **He is touched by a fair ball in fair territory before the ball
>     has touched or passed an infielder**. The ball is dead and
>     no runner may score, nor runners advance, except runners
>     forced to advance.

Comment: Damn, when I pictured being hit I thought it would be injury wise. Has there been any serious hits or are they all small incidents like this?

Comment: I didn't find a specific incident, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WURDv6Ky68c) **could have been** a "serious hit." The possibility is present, but I can't imagine that it has never happened...

Comment: Oh, I'm 100% sure it happened in the history of baseball. I'm just curious if it's ever happened in the pros. Especially with how common it is for pitchers to catch the ball when it flies towards them. That new link is essentially what I wanted to know. Thanks